# Laravel how to secure blade from change in inspect element

Tags: php, laravel

I have conditions in blade and working fine but little bit worry if somebody comes and use inspect element so he can add href and link and make button as example working if it was disabled, so what is the good way to secure my code

```
@if (auth()->user()->customer->package_id>0)   
     <li class="btn_disabled"> Allready Purchased</li>
@elseif(auth()->user()->customer->package_id==null)
     <li class="buttonprice"><a href="{{route('updatepackage')}}">Purchase</a></li>
@endif
```

Comment: Do it from post method instead of get method then, avoid href links for security links. Control from javascript methods using ajax calls

Comment: Do it from the backend and add validation from the backend if user send the malicious request you should validate it from the backend before processing any data

Comment: Every request should be validated and authenticated at the backend, before consuming or processing them.

Comment: how can I validate this?